# Why a NonNegativeIntegers variable gets a float value in Baron solver

Tags: solver, pyomo, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am using pyomo and Baron to solve a MINLP. I declared a NonNegativeIntegers variable but when Baron solves the problem, the variable is: 2e-06 !!

How is it possible?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of tolerances any integer variable can be slightly non-integer. This is normal and also happens with linear solvers.